# Procmail: filter subcject then alter mail body

Tags: procmail

I have to cut mail body below certain string. Additionally message is base-64 encoded. This recipe works fine:

```
:0fb
| base64 -d
:0fb
|sed '/string/,$d'
:0fb
| base64
```

Recipe first decodes body, does what I need, then encodes back what remains. 
But if I tried to add some filtering it ends with message with empty body:

```
:0
* ^Subject.*sometext
{
:0fb
|base 64 -d
:0fb
|sed '/string/,$d'
:0fb
|base 64
}
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you are missing a pipe character before `base64 -d`.

However, you can easily collapse this into a single action.

```
:0fb
* ^Subject:.*sometext
| base64 -d | sed '/string/,$d' | base64
```

Doing this processing in a shell pipeline is slightly unattractive in that there really isn't a way to avoid the filter when it is a no-op (i.e. when `string` is not encoded in the message body).  For efficiency and elegance, you might want to convert this into a simple Python (or what have you) script which just aborts if the string you want to filter is not present.

Comment: Hmm, i like bash scripting :) Pipe character was lost during editing my post, corrected.